# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker Throws Exception in C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to authenticate with Google using `OAuth` inside a Windows 8 App. I am using the Google .NET Client API for this, following this [tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2#Windows_8_Applications). However I keep getting an exception when I use the `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` class.

The code I have is copy/pasted from the linked tutorial. The client_secrets.json contains the file I downloaded from the Google API Console. I did check that it is copied to the installed app and that I can open it. The Calendar API is turned on.

```
UserCredential credidential = null;    
credidential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/client_secrets.json"),
                        new[] { Uri.EscapeUriString(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar) },
                        "user", CancellationToken.None);
```

Surrounding this line in try/catch tells me that it fails because of:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Exception: The process terminated unexpectedly. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8007042B)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeBroker.<ReceiveCodeAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
>   in
>   c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\output\default\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.WinRT\OAuth2\AuthorizationCodeBroker.cs:line
>   69    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.d__0.MoveNext()
>   in
>   c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\output\default\Src\GoogleApis.Auth\OAuth2\AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.cs:line
>   74
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeWinRTInstalledApp.<AuthorizeAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
>   in
>   c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\output\default\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.WinRT\OAuth2\AuthorizationCodeWinRTInstalledApp.cs:line
>   65
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__6.MoveNext()
>   in
>   c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\output\default\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.WinRT\OAuth2\GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs:line
>   73
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.<AuthorizeAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
>   in
>   c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\output\default\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.WinRT\OAuth2\GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs:line
>   48
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at kk_youtube_metro.GroupedItemsPage.d__5.MoveNext() in
>   c:\Users\Karol\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\kk-youtube-metro\kk-youtube-metro\GroupedItemsPage.xaml.cs:line
>   68
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: The process terminated unexpectedly. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007042B)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeBroker.d__10.MoveNext()
>   in
>   c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\output\default\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.WinRT\OAuth2\AuthorizationCodeBroker.cs:line
>   69<---

What am I missing?

Comment: show us the code surrounding `AuthorizationCodeBroker.cs:line 69`

Comment: Maybe the following thread will be helpful to you - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7605fcab-8318-4dae-a873-441bd0685863/webauthenticationbrokerauthenticateasync-throws-exception-on-the-desktop?forum=winappswithcsharp. The problem is baed on the core library call to: WebAuthenticationResult result = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync
                    (WebAuthenticationOptions.UseTitle, url.Build(), new Uri(GoogleAuthConsts.ApprovalUrl));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7605fcab-8318-4dae-a873-441bd0685863/webauthenticationbrokerauthenticateasync-throws-exception-on-the-desktop?forum=winappswithcsharp) posted by pelayal in the comments to the question provided the solution. There was a problem with my profile. Creating a new account fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Check above

- Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async
- and deploy their dlls with your application